# Is there any Ubuntu command video course?

Tags: command-line

I would like to learn how to use Ubuntu command line, so I decided to google a little bit. In my search I only find tons of books, but any video course that explains how to use the terminal.

Is there any video course that explain how to use the terminal?

Comment: Try: https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+command+line+tutorial+video

Comment: Reading books/tutorials/articles is the best way. Videos are usually too simple and broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find courses on Udemy or lynda.com or any other sites. But those are not free. You can watch these tutorials on youtube.

[youtube link 1](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLW5y1tjAOzI2ZYTlMdGzCV8AJuoqW5lKB)
and
[youtube link 2](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGCkg2uj3PxUWhMDuTw3VKjM)

Hope it can help you.

Comment: I use Lynda.com , but I do not know which curse I have to choose

Comment: @Xalsar I'm not sure they even have Linux terminal courses.

Comment: They have a bash curse, this is linux-terminal right?

Comment: @Xalsar True. But do check out the Codecademy course, it let's you test out things in a controlled enviroment.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of tutorials on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=terminal%20tutorial).

There's also interactive course available at [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-the-command-line). Highly reccommend if you haven't used terminal before.